# Power BI - dataset refresh completion data PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am using PowerShell to refresh my powerbi.com datasets programmaticlly. This is all working fine. What would be helpful, however, is if there is a way to retrieve the refresh completion time data from Microsoft. I could list the process I'm using to kick off the refresh, but that is well documented and not pertinent to this question.

Since powerbi.com shows the dataset refresh completion time, it would stand to reason that I could grab that data, but I cannot find any documentation on this. Has anyone on here tried to grab this data (screenshot below)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of POST method, which will trigger a refresh, i.e. this is the [Refresh Dataset In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdatasetingroup) API, change the method to GET to use [Get Refresh History In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getrefreshhistoryingroup) API. This will return information about the refreshes of this dataset. So the PowerShell code could be something like this:

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

$username = "my super strong password"
$password = "user@domain.com" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force

$groupId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$datasetId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential

$refreshes_response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$groupId/datasets/$datasetId/refreshes" -Method Get 

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount

$refreshes_response_json = ConvertFrom-Json $refreshes_response

foreach ($refresh in $refreshes_response_json.value)
{
    Write-Output "refreshType: $($refresh.refreshType), startTime: $($refresh.startTime), endTime: $($refresh.endTime), status: $($refresh.status)"
}
```

You can also limit the number of refreshes returned by providing a number in the URL:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes?$top={$top}
```

But if the last one is not successful, you may want to look at older events to find the last successful one. Also look at the status of the refresh, because it may still be in progress (it will say `Unknown` in such case).

Comment: This is perfect. I had missed this in the documentation. I'm using the GET method to retrieve the dataset and group ids, but didn't see how to get the refresh data. Thank you so much. One thing I can't seem to get to work, however, is the $top=1. I see it in the documentation, but when I execute out of powershell, I still get the latest 20 (no matter the number I put at the end).

Comment: Most likely `$top` is evaluated as a variable, because the string is quoted with double quotes. Quote it with single quotes to avoid evaluation of the expressions in it.

Comment: Sorry i'm slow on the powershell part. Here's what I have and neither worked: $refreshes_response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "groups/$groupId/datasets/$datasetId/refreshes?$top=1" -Method Get as well as $refreshes_response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "groups/$groupId/datasets/$datasetId/refreshes?$top='1'" -Method Get

Comment: In `"groups/$groupId/datasets/$datasetId/refreshes?$top=1"` expressions are evaluated, because it is quoted using double quotes, and `$groupId`, `$datasetId` and `$top` are replaced with their values (`$top` most likely is replaced with an empty string). So you need to evaluate `$groupId` and `$datasetId`, but not `$top`. One thing you can do is to concatenate a double quoted string with a single quoted string, like this `$refreshes_response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$groupId/datasets/$datasetId/refreshes" + '?$top=3') -Method Get` for example